# How to indent JSON data inside of TextMate, Emacs, BBEdit, or Sublime Text 2?

Tags: json, emacs, textmate, sublimetext2, bbedit

[**Update:** 8 hours after this question was posted, the author of [JSON bundle](https://github.com/textmate/json.tmbundle) was notified of the issue and he fixed it.]

I have the following JSON data in a file `application.json`, shown at the end of this post, and I have used TextMate with the [JSON bundle](https://github.com/textmate/json.tmbundle), Emacs, BBEdit, and Sublime Text 2 to properly indent it, but all seemed like they couldn't.

Both TextMate and Sublime Text 2 insisted that the first `{` should not be indented, and the first major issue was for the closing brace for `"child": {`.  Both TextMate and Sublime Text 2 refused to align the `}` under the left side of `"child": {`.  Emacs kept on indenting further and further for each line, and BBEdit didn't seem to have an re-indent function at all (could this be?).

Is there a way to properly indent the file, or are TextMate and Sublime Text 2 both doing the right thing for the JSON data?

```
[ 
{
    "settings": [ "master" ],
    "appPort": "8666",
    "specs": {
        "frame" : {
            "type" : "HTMLFrameMojit",

            "config": {
                "deploy": true,
                "child": {
                    "type" : "HelloWorldMojit"
                    },
                    "assets": {
                        "top": {
                            "css": [
                            "/static/HelloWorldMojit/assets/index.css"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        },
        {
            "settings": [ "environment:development" ],
            "staticHandling": {
                "forceUpdate": true
            }
        }
        ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just corrected this issue in the bundle, for 2.0 users the bundle should update within 24 hours with the correction.

Answer (score 42):

**EDIT: For BBEdit use siegel's suggestion of Text > Reformat Document**

*Original Reply:*

I [found](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/11/11/making-json-output-more-readable-with-bbedit/) a solution for BBEdit that is easy and works well.

Put the following script in
`~/Library/Containers/BBEdit/Data/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/Text Filters/FormatJSON.sh` (on MacOS 11 Big Sur, or above)

For MacOS 10.15 Catalina and below, use this location: `~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/Text Filters/FormatJSON.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m json.tool
```

1. Open a JSON file in BBEdit. There is no need to restart BBEdit because BBEdit rocks!
2. Select **Text > Apply Text Filter > FormatJSON**

I tested this with a JSON file that had 3,612,683 characters on a single line. BBEdit opened this file and reformatted without showing a "Spinning Beachball of Death" busy-wait mouse cursor.

Comment: There should be another / between Text Filters and FormatJSON.

Comment: AppCode has built in support for JSON and should reformat it, but I haven't tried it, and it is not inexpensive.

Comment: Note that this may reorder the file, not merely reindent it.

Comment: The folder location listed for Catalina and below is in fact the correct location for above too, certainly Mac OS 12 (Monterey)

Comment: The folder location on MacOS 12 Monterey is `~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/Text Filters`.

Comment: You might need `python3 -m json.tool`, depending on how you installed Python.

Comment: I'm on macOS Ventura. @SteveU suggested location of `~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/Text Filters/FormatJSON.sh` containing @Glorfindel suggested `python3 -m json.tool` works on my Mac.

Answer (score 10):

In BBEdit 14.0 and later, "Reformat Document" on the text menu will reflow JSON. You can also use the built-in [Language Server Support](https://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/lsp-notes.html) with a JSON language server that supports reformatting.

Comment: the feature workable!

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1: Using `Python`

This answer is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19429447/2987755) answer, except I am using `python file` to do the JSON format.

1. Exit `bbedit` application if it is open,
2. put following script [pretty-json.py](https://github.com/dineshbhagat/mac-configurations/blob/master/bbedit/pretty-json.py) in  `~/Library/Application\ Support/BBEdit/Text\ Filters/` path

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# You can change above she-bang line depending on your Mac configuration

import sys
import json

def main():
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    try:
        obj = json.loads(input)
    except Exception as e:
        print input + "\n\nERROR: " + str(e)
        return 1
    print(json.dumps(obj, indent=2))
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

3. To Test, open a JSON file in BBEdit.
4. Select `Text` --> `Apply Text Filter` --> `pretty-json.py`
5. If you face any issue like formatting error, then the above script will add error in New file and will not change the original JSON.
   which is not the case with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19429447/2987755) answer

Ref: https://gist.github.com/brokaw/95ade1358954cd97d0f2c8e992e14b08

For more info: Refer [this](https://github.com/dineshbhagat/mac-configurations/tree/master/bbedit)

The above filter works fine for smaller JSON files, but if the JSON file is large(~ 40MB) then formatting will be slow.

To solve this, use the following solution

Solution 2: Using `jq`

For faster json formatting,

1. Install [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) `brew install jq`
2. Check if you are able to execute `jq` in terminal, or need a full path, add whichever works in following file in place of `jq`
3. Add `fast-json-pretty.sh` file in `~/Library/Application\ Support/BBEdit/Text\ Filters/` location
4. Restart bbedit.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
jq
```

Comment: Solution 2 totally rocks and you do _not_ need to quit / restart BBEdit. In fact you can _use_ BBEdit to create and save the shell script and then you can use it, immediately, on a json file that was already open.

Comment: All credit goes to the contributors of `jq` library.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://jsonprettyprint.com/ Textmate and Sublime aren't doing the right thing.

What version of Emacs did you use?

With 24.2.1, your JSON blob indented perfectly without issues in `js-mode` (Emac's default javascript major-mode).

---

If you do any significant Javascript development I recommend checkint out js2-mode https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode, which turns Emacs into a great JS IDE.

Comment: I tried the newest Emacs on Fedora (Emacs 24.1.1) and it worked perfectly, so the question is, how can Emacs on the Mac be upgraded?  (update: my Emacs is 22.1.1 on OS X Lion, and following the instruction for js2-mode on GitHub, it won't add the `js2-mode` to Emcas)

Answer (score 0):

### Sublime Pretty JSON

[Sublime Pretty JSON](https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson) indents the first `{` well.
This is what I get:

```
[
  {
    "settings": [
      "master"
    ],
    "appPort": "8666",
    "specs": {
      "frame": {
        "type": "HTMLFrameMojit",
        "config": {
          "deploy": true,
          "child": {
            "type": "HelloWorldMojit"
          },
          "assets": {
            "top": {
              "css": [
                "/static/HelloWorldMojit/assets/index.css"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "settings": [
      "environment:development"
    ],
    "staticHandling": {
      "forceUpdate": true
    }
  }
]
```

---

**Installation**

Within Sublime Text 2: Preference => Package Control => Install Package => "Pretty Json" => Restart Sublime => Select JSON Text => Press:

- Linux: ctrl+alt+j
- Windows: ctrl+alt+j
- OS X: cmd+ctrl+j

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution simply using Google Chrome or NodeJS itself, and here is how:

Just open up the Google Chrome dev tool or NodeJS prompt, and type in

```
obj =
```

and copy and paste the object into it, so it will be like

```
obj = [
      { 
        // etc
```

Now, in Google Chrome, just type

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)
```

and you will have the formatted JSON.  In NodeJS, since it prints out the `\n` verbatim, you can use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4))
```

If you want the indentation to be just 2 spaces, just use `2` instead of `4`.

If you want the indentation to be tabs instead of spaces, simply use

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, "\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a script file `fast-json-pretty.sh` in `~/Library/Application\ Support/BBEdit/Text\ Filters/`
2. Insert the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/local/bin/jq .
```

3. Apply the text filter as follows: `Menu bar` --> `Text` --> `Apply Text Filter` --> `fast-json-pretty`

This is a reworked version of DKB's version of his JQ script as it, at least for me, required the full path and a dot (.) at the end to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see which version of python is installed:

using json_pretty will only work if the python interpreter is whatever is installed in the shell being called.  For example, my json_pretty works and I have modded it as follows on Ventura:

```
#!/bin/zsh
python3 -m json.tool
```